# Bootstrap conflict for modal and editable jQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my project.

Two things I want to do.

1. Display the book records.
2. On clicking on any book show a pop-up and this pop-up will have the record list which can be edited(inline edit)

I have two set of jQuery files (one is for modal window and the other one is for inline editable).

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
            $(url).modal('open');
        } else {
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
            }).success(function () {
                $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
            });
        }
    });

    $('.bookname').editable({
        type: 'text',
        url: 'post.php',
        title: 'Enter username',
        validate: function (value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my html code:

```
<a data-target="#" class="bookname" id="bookname" href="pop1.php?id=<?php echo $row['book_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"> <?php echo $row['book_name']; ?></a>
```

When I run both the js files seperately I see no issues. When I try to integrate the inline edit inside a modal window there is problem with the modal window close button and also with the inline edit is not working.

Is the issue related to version(version problem)

Any one have faced such problems. Can someone help me out or guide me with an example.

Thanks
Kimz

Comment: can you post the javascript error you get in the console of your browser?

Comment: This is the error i'm getting
TypeError: e is undefined
if (this === e.target){

Comment: noobcode - please check my question again. i have pasted the code

Comment: Can you check if all the JS files that you have included in script tag are pointing correct and not giving 404 error.

Comment: noobcode - thanks again. yup, all are included, and i have checked twice with the source code also. help me out !!!